# Override default arguments of a function used in Map

Tags: python

I am trying to identify how we can pass in the default arguments that have been defined for  a function when it is used in map

For example for the following snippet:

```
def func1(a,x=3,y=2):
    return (a + x)*y
lst = [1,2,3]
print map(func1,lst)
```

Is there a way to override the values for x & y so that for each element of lst x=4 and y=3  without using lambda or list comprehension?

Comment: You can write another function and use that instead.

Comment: or you can use lambda and keep the x, y as variables.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (not mentioned in the duplicate target, and slightly less relevant there) is to use a nested function, where the outer function sets the values and returns the inner function, which is what is then executed in the `map`:

```
def func1(x=3,y=2):
    def inner(a):
        return (a + x)*y
    return inner

lst = [1, 2, 3]
print map(func1(), lst)
print map(func1(x=4, y=3), lst)
```

Note the added `()` even if you don't want to overwrite the default arguments, otherwise it will apply the outer function to every element of `lst`.

The outer function is basically a function factory that produces inner functions with correctly set parameters.